# Add file via button using Dropzone plugin

Tags: dropzone.js

Is it possible to use an external button to add file using Dropzone plugin?
I found this [documentation](https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Upload-all-files-with-a-button) but it doesn't answer my question.Indeed, I can't be able to add file using an handler event such as click. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I guess you want your button to have the clickable option, isn't it? 
If so you should configure your Dropzone for this like that:

```
Dropzone.options.validationForm = {
  clickable: "#your_button_id",
  //rest of your code
}
```

If it isn't the answer you're looking for maybe you could try explain better what you want or put a snippet of your code :)